# has_object_permission not called from put or patch request

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have permissions class P1:

```
class P1(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print('has_permission')
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print('has_object_permission')
        return True
```

I have a test class:

```
class Test1(APITestCase):
    def test_f1(self):
        response = self.client.put(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

This put request doesnt call `has_object_permission` func. It only calls `has_permission` func.

Comment: Same problem here. View has overriden `get_queryset()` method

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your view, it's hard to say, but it's possible that you have overridden the  `get_object` method. If you do that, you have to manually call `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)` on your retrieved object.

As you probably know, `has_object_permission` is checked against the specific row in your model.

The [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) show an example on how a `get_object` method would look if you want to check for permissions:

```py
def get_object(self):
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

And on a side note, your `has_object_permission` method always returns `True`, so your testcase will always fail.

Comment: I did not overwrite `get_object`. I did overwrite `get_queryset()` method

Comment: well, without seeing the implementation of the view, its hard to say.